# Sqlite Browser issue working with Entity Framework

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6, sqlbrowser

In DB I have a table (let it be Names), in project have DbSet Names field for that table. When adding row in browser it loads into project fine. 
But when in project I do:

```
Names.Add(someName);
MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It doesn't show in browser but loads next time in project.
If I add in browser another row it erase everything of what I have added from project and returns those rows what shows in browser only.
Is it bug a bug?

In a giagnostic tool there are also some errors. Mybe that is connected somehow:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsdfV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was that database file copies in bin/Degug folder and renew only if you made changes in root database file.
https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/1103